# Active Record Query used "NOT IN"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to query excluding array lists of id kept as cookie.  And I got stuck with

```
where('author_name iLIKE ? OR quote iLIKE ? AND id NOT IN ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "#{disable}").all(:order => sorting)
```

From this code above, it will be generated this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM quotations WHERE author_name LIKE '%' + 'search' + '%' OR quote LIKE '%' + 'search' + '%' AND id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: what part of it is the issue in the sql query ?? the LIKE part ?

Comment: What version of Rails and Ruby are you using?  Running the same thing I am getting `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%M%'`  I'm on Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0p0

Comment: Also, you *might* want to put parentheses around your `OR` parameters so they are treated as one condition.  You may get some unexpected behavior with the way it's written now.